# AWS kubernetes Ingress URL is not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb, amazon-alb

Using below template when i am trying to create Ingress, it is creating but when i am hitting the host url it's not working. Getting error on browser "This page can't be reached". Can you please suggest.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myservice-service
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}, {"HTTP": 80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myservice-service.mynamespace.eks.aws
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: myservice-service
              servicePort: 8080
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: can you share the logs from aws alb ingress controller? Is this problem only when you use ingress? Are you able to access it without ingress?

Comment: I could not find the controller. I tried to search using below commands but i could not find it.  kubectl -n mynamespace get pod | grep "alb"

kubectl -n mynamespace get pod | grep "ingress-controller"                                               Can you please assist if i am looking for logs correctly ?

Comment: Make sure your pod is serving. To check try, `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 8080:8080 -n <namespace>` and then access the application using `http:\\localhost:8080`. If this works fine, check the service deployment manifest.

Comment: Fast forward, i am experiencing the same issue, @sagarverma

Comment: as @VamshiSiddarth said, if you can port forward it and access the api then the problem is in the ingress service, install the vscode kubernetes extension to check all your pods and services and do port forwards easily